# font of downloaded project not recognized by android adt

Tags: android, adt

I have recently downladed a demo project for the research of my project but adt is not recocnizing fonts of almost all comments in the downladed project.I can't read the comments.Is there a way to make these comments redable?[image]

Answer (score 0):

as there are some parts readable (AccessToken and UserInfo) i would bet, that these comments are in a language that does not use the "normal" letters a-z.

using some of the classnames in your code snipped i found [this github repo](https://github.com/platformanes/android360) looking at the [files](https://github.com/platformanes/android360/blob/master/android/src/com/qh360/appserver/QihooUserInfo.java) there let you see that these comments are written in chinese or something like that.

to setup your eclipse to show the correct text you can change the font under `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts`. but then the text will still be chinese. so if you don't understand chinese, this wouldn't help you very much. ;)

Comment: I tried to set font in my adt like the way you explained but did't find a way to change font over there.even if i get those texts in chinese i would use google translate to translate them. Sorry for my less familiarization to adt on changing fonts

Comment: what di you mean by "but did't find a way to change font over there"?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OB4-roECY8I here is a youtube video for font changing in Eclipse/ADT